# Exercise 2.28 of the book "Mathemathical Proof: A Transition to advanced mathematics (4th edition)"

Tags: logic, solution-verification

I have a problem with an exercise of the Chapter 2 (Logic) of the book Mathemathical Proof: A transition to advanced mathematics.

It says:

**Consider the statement (implication):If Bill takes Sam to the concert, then Sam will take Bill to dinner. Which of the following implies that this statement is true?**

**(a) Sam takes Bill to dinner only if Bill takes Sam to the concert.**

**(b) Either Bill doesn’t take Sam to the concert or Sam takes Bill to dinner.**

**(c) Bill takes Sam to the concert.**

**(d) Bill takes Sam to the concert and Sam takes Bill to dinner.**

**(e) Bill takes Sam to the concert and Sam doesn’t take Bill to dinner.**

**(f) The concert is canceled.**

**(g) Sam doesn’t attend the concert.**

The answer in the solution manual of the book is the following:
**2.28 (b), (d), (f), (g) are true.**

Why *(f)* and *(g)* are solutions? They say nothing about the truth of the proposition, right?
Moreover, I don't know why *(b) (P∨Q)* implies the truth of the statement implication (P⇒Q). Because if *P* is true and *Q* is false, *P∨Q* is true, but *P⇒Q* is not.

In exchange, I see *(d)* is correct. My **solution** would be ***(d)***.

I may be making some mistake. I'd like you to point it out or to clarify if my solution is right. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this not an exercise in temporal logic? Both the antecedent and consequent are in the future tense. IMHO if authors want to illustrate material implication with "real-world" examples, they should probably stick to statements in the present tense.

Comment: In temporal logic: Sam is Bill's concert guest at time $t_1$ in the future. Bill is Sam's dinner guest at time $t_2 > t_1$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. 

Comment: Are there several types of logic? Wow. I thought it was two or so, but I haven't heard about temporal logic never.

Comment: In this case, it's just predicate logic and set theory with a variable for time (as in physics). Not really a different kind of logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given conditional statement is false *only* in the case that

1. “Bill takes Sam to the concert” is true, *and*
2. “Sam will take Bill to dinner” is false.

In another combination of the truth values of these two clauses, the conditional statement is true.

In case that “the concert is canceled”, the clause (1) becomes false, then the conditional statement is true regardless of whether “Sam will take Bill to dinner” or not.

Likewise, for the clause “Sam doesn’t attend the concert” which renders (1) false.

Comment: But what about (b)?

Comment: Either$\ldots$or$\ldots$ pattern is taken in the exclusive sense: Either X is true or Y is true, but not both X and Y are true. Therefore, (b) has the form: Either not-(1) is true or (2) is true, but not both. not-(1) is true is equivalent to (1) is false, hence the case is the same as (f) and (g). If (2) is true, the conditional statement is true regardless of whether (1) is true or not. Therefore, (b) expresses the truth conditions for the conditional statement.